# "И смех(,) и грех"

Tags: пунктуация

Интересует поговорка "и смех(,) и грех". Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в ней запятая?
Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая не нужна: и смех и грех.

Это, действительно, устойчивое словосочетание, но не стоит здесь искать обязательного противопоставления.  Правило  на эту тему звучит примерно так: В некоторых случаях при тесном смысловом единстве двух однородных членов с союзами И…И, НИ…НИ  запятая между ними не ставится, что особенно характерно для синонимов, антонимов и устойчивых выражений.

Например: Лесам нет ни конца ни края (синонимы). Душа обязана трудиться и день и ночь (антонимы). Она за тебя и в огонь и в воду готова. На другой день, ни свет ни заря, Лиза уже проснулась (фразеологизмы).

Также возможно авторское сближение признаков: В шатре и тихо и темно. Были и лето и осень дождливы. Но при отсутствии сближения запятая ставится: "Я один у окошка, ни гостя, ни друга не жду".

Answer (score 5):

Я бы запятую не ставил: ***"и смех и грех"***.

Правило таково, что в устойчивых сочетаниях противопоставляемые объекты, соединяемые парными союзами "и"..."и" или "ни"..."ни", запятой не требуют.
Тут все условия выполняются, некоторое сомнение только в том, насколько эти два члена "смех" и "грех" противопоставляются. Но думаю, что именно так.

Словари это вполне подтверждают.
[И смех и грех | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/70254)
(несколько раз в тексте - из разных источников)